# How to get nnoremap <buffer> to work in different buffers?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, terminal-buffer

I have a hotkey that runs python of the first buffer when I press F8 and outputs the outputs to the bottom.

However, this hotkey does not work when I switch buffers... it only works when I am on the first buffer.. Why would this be the case?

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F8> :! python3 #1<cr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifier `<buffer>` means the mapping is only effective for the buffer in which the command was run.

This is heavily used in ftplugins to create local mappings; *e.g.*, you might want <kbd>F8</kbd> to run `:!python3 %` in python buffers but `:make` in C buffers. You can make a single function that does this and bind it globally, but then you have to keep updating the function for new filetypes you work with.

Instead, bind <kbd>F8</kbd> with a `<buffer>` mapping in the relevant ftplugins. Then each new filetype gets its own binding, and the binding is located with all the other file-type specific settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... removing `<buffer>` seems to do the trick...
I am not sure I had it there in the first place...(I copied it from a code snippet)

```
nnoremap <F8> :! python3 #1<cr>
```