# Conditional Key Mapping in Neovim Based on File Type

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, terminal, filetype, nvchad

How can I do in nvim if the file type is `js` do this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<A-1>', [[:w | split term://node % <CR>]], { noremap = true, silent = true})
```

else if file type is `lua` do this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<A-1>", [[:w | split term://lua %<CR>]], { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim!. Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further. Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Related [1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37210/10604), [2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31868/10604), [3](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39122/10604)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to define `buffer` mapping in the `filetype` configuration.

I would have a `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/js.lua` file with the following content:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<A-1>', [[:w | split term://node % ]], { noremap = true, silent = true, buffer = true})
```

And a `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/lua.lua` file with the following content:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<A-1>", [[:w | split term://lua %<CR>]], { noremap = true, silent = true , buffer = true})
```

These files are executed when the `filetype` is set to their corresponding value. The `buffer` option makes the mapping only applying to the corresponding buffer.